# How do I deploy Qt libraries with an application?

Tags: linux, qt, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

This should be really simple, but I'm having trouble. I want to include some shared Qt libraries with my application in the installation folder so the user doesn't have to download Qt separately. On Windows, this seemed to work fine, but Ubuntu complains about not being to find the Qt libraries when they are in the same folder as the application.

How do I add the installation directory to  shared library search path?

Comment: Be careful, as this is one thing that could violate licensing rights.  Check first if Qt libraries allow you to distribute their software without a permit.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add the installation directory to shared library search path by adding the following lines to the .pro file, which set the rpath of the binary to $ORIGIN (the install folder). I needed to add the location of QT libs on my current machine (/usr/lib/qt5.5 and /usr/lib/qt5.5/lib) so that the project would build in QtCreator.

```
unix:!macx {
    # suppress the default RPATH if you wish
    QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH=
    # add your own with quoting gyrations to make sure $ORIGIN gets to the command line unexpanded
    QMAKE_LFLAGS += "-Wl,-rpath,\'\$$ORIGIN\':/usr/lib/qt5.5:/usr/lib/qt5.5/lib"
}
```

(The `unix:!macx` line makes it apply to linux only)

Answer (score 0):

Windows, Linux and OSX behave quite differently. Windows is easiest: dump all the dll's in the application dir. OSX is next and Linux is most difficult.

Linux has certain search paths for searching shared objects. These search paths  are mainly system libraries and possibly some user libraries. As you do not want to mess around with system files of your user one would prefer to have the shared objects in the application dir. This is possible but you have to tell Linux to read that directory. You can do this with setting the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH. You can do this with a script. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34155856/ld-library-path-failing-while-trying-to-run-qt-app/34178548#34178548).